# Não consigo usar Webpack no meu projeto

Tags: webpack

Estou aprendendo react, e nas videos-aulas que estou vendo, ele manda instalar o webpack global:

```
npm i -g webpack
```

foi feita a instalação com sucesso.

só que no vídeo é criado um diretório `dist` com arquivo `bundle.js` só que no meu projeto não aparecem esses arquivos. como faço para gerar eles?

1. Não tenho o node modules localmente e Estou usando Windows 10

sempre que tento executar o webpack, ele me da essa resposta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tu precisa ter o webpack declarado no teu package.json e criar um arquivo chamado  webpack.config.js onde ficará as configurações do webpack para teu projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Com o webpack instalado, faça a configuração do seu webpack.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
 entry: './main.js',
 output: {
   filename: './bundle.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist')
 }
  };
```

coloque no seu package.json um método para iniciar:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server"
 }
```

execute o script com o npm start.

A lógica em si é pegar o conteúdo do entry (o seu arquivo principal, que no caso é ./main.js) e transformá-lo e despejar no output (que no caso, ficará dist/bundle.js).